# Code Error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, typeerror

I'm trying to save a .txt, but it does this error: `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper`

Here is the code:

```py
def saveas():
    window.filename =  filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("text files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))
    file=open(window.filename, 'w')
    file.writelines(escritura.get('1.0', END))
    file.close()
    print(escritura.get('1.0', END))
```

If you know it, please, help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.name` attribute to access the file --> `window.filename.name`.

**Ex:**

```
def saveas():
    window.filename =  filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("text files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))
    file=open(window.filename.name, 'w')
    file.writelines(escritura.get('1.0', END))
    file.close()
    print(escritura.get('1.0', END))
```

Comment: because `window.filename` is a `TextIOWrapper` object. You need to access the file path using .name attribute. Try printing `window.filename` see it

Answer (score 0):

`escritura.get('1.0', END)` is maybe an already open file, so maybe you should do `escritura.get('1.0', END).read()`, since i cant comment yet, can you do `type(escritura.get('1.0', END))`